# How to access tagName of custom node in DOM

Tags: javascript, xml

I am reading a custom xml-file with custom tags such as `<section></section>` into a variable `text`. I then apply the following few lines of *plain javascript*:

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/xml');
console.log(xmlDoc.documentElement);
parseDOM(xmlDoc.documentElement);
```

where

```
function parseDOM(node){
    type = node.nodeName;
    console.log(type);
    for(child in node.children){
        parseDOM(child);
    }
}
```

The `console.log(xmlDoc.documentElement)` part prints out the complete hierarchy without any problems, in particular with the tags having the correct names. Unfortunately the `console.log(type)` part prints out "undefined" for all my custom tags.

> How can I test, whether the node at hand is of the custom type `<section></section>`? I was expecting `node.nodeName == 'section'` to work, but apparently it does not... And while we are at it, how can I test, whether the current node is a text-block?

Thank you very much for your support.

My goal is to replace the tags (e.g. turn `<section>` into `<h2>`), but also might do some heavier alterations to some tags in the future. I know that there very likely is some library perfectly suited for the job, but I am using this project to finally to get back writing some code, so I would prefer if the solution remains within standard javascript. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're also iterating through the properties of [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (ie `item`, `namedItem` and `length`).  Try using for..of instead of for..in - `for(let child of node.children)`

Comment: Brilliant! I am not really familiar with javascript, so I wouldn't have thought about this. Can I detect the text-nodes with this as well?

Comment: `Can I detect the text-nodes` not with node.children because that returns elements.  [node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) should have all the text nodes, though.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!